# How to enforce the same width for table cells?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the text following the pictures have the same width as the picture in this table? (between the red lines shown in the picture). I tried width property with CSS but it didn't work.

In the same context, how can I enforce the same height for all cells as well?

[image]

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?v=1" alt="picture not available" height="200" width="300">

    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?v=2" alt="picture not available" height="200" width="300">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?v=3" alt="picture not available" height="200" width="300">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="page1.html">
        <h3>Vaccin covid-19 en 2021 ?</h3>
      </a>
      <p>
        Avec covid-19, c'est necessaire de nous immuniser ! On a une nouvelle collection des complements alimentaires qui sont benefiques et riches en vitamines !
        <a href="page1.html">
          <h2>Read more ...</h2>
        </a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="page2.html">
        <h3>Nouveaux : complements alimentaires pour vous immuniser !</h3>
      </a>
      <p>
        Avec covid-19, c'est necessaire de nous immuniser ! On a une nouvelle collection des complements alimentaires qui sont benefiques et riches en vitamines !
        <a href="page2.html">
          <h2>Read more ...</h2>
        </a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="page3.html">
        <h3>Marathon sponsorisé par E-Pharma</h3>
      </a>
      <p>
        Venez pour le marathon de 28/12/2020 ou on va faire beaucoup d'activites de sensibilisation contre la maladie de cancer de seins ! Vous etes bienvenues !
        <a href="page3.html">
          <h2>Read more ...</h2>
        </a>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `<table>` code seems fine and your `td` have the width of `300px`. I think that there is another CSS rule that is altering the table. Please post more details.

Comment: I used this CSS code :
table
{
    text-align : center;
}

Comment: You're using a `<table>` for layout; don't do that: it's an obsolete practice, it's non-semantic, it's difficult for assistive technology to parse usefully, it's more complicated to maintain and there are far easier methods using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width` in `a` and `p` tag to set same width as image

```css
td a,
td p{
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>            
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="picture not available" height="200" width="300">

        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="picture not available" height="200" width="300">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="picture not available" height="200" width="300">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="page1.html"><h3>Vaccin covid-19 en 2021 ?</h3></a>
            <p>
                Avec covid-19, c'est necessaire de nous immuniser ! On a une 
                nouvelle collection des complements alimentaires qui sont benefiques
                et riches en vitamines !
                <a href="page1.html"><h2>Read more ...</h2></a>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="page2.html"><h3>Nouveaux : complements alimentaires pour vous immuniser !</h3></a>
            <p>
                Avec covid-19, c'est necessaire de nous immuniser ! On a une 
                nouvelle collection des complements alimentaires qui sont benefiques
                et riches en vitamines !
                <a href="page2.html"><h2>Read more ...</h2></a>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="page3.html"><h3>Marathon sponsorisé par E-Pharma</h3></a>
            <p>
                Venez pour le marathon de 28/12/2020 ou on va faire beaucoup d'activites
                de sensibilisation contre la maladie de cancer de seins ! 
                Vous etes bienvenues !
                <a href="page3.html"><h2>Read more ...</h2></a>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```